# Should the certificate signing request generated from a self signed certificate using openssl show extensions attributes?

Tags: openssl, x509

I have a self signed certificate which shows basic constraints listed, but a signing request generated from it doesn't show these attributes such as [v3_req]. How can I make it visible? I am using openssl for certificate generation.

Scenario:

I create a self signed certificate using:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt -config openssl.conf

When I check the certificate, it shows required extensions:
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout

Now I create a CSR from this
openssl x509 -x509toreq -in certificate.crt -out CSR.csr -signkey privateKey.key

When I check the CSR using:
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in CSR.csr

It doesn't show required extensions.

My openssl.conf file

```html
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME   = .
RANDFILE  = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file  = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section  = new_oids

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions  = 
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca' and 'req'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default  # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir  = ./demoCA  # Where everything is kept
certs  = $dir/certs  # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir  = $dir/crl  # Where the issued crl are kept
database = $dir/index.txt # database index file.
new_certs_dir = $dir/newcerts  # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem  # The CA certificate
serial  = $dir/serial   # The current serial number
crl  = $dir/crl.pem   # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
RANDFILE = $dir/private/.rand # private random number file

x509_extensions = usr_cert  # The extentions to add to the cert

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions = crl_ext

default_days = 365   # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30   # how long before next CRL
default_md = md5   # which md to use.
preserve = no   # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy  = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName  = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName = match
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName  = supplied
emailAddress  = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName  = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName  = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName  = supplied
emailAddress  = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits  = 1024
default_keyfile  = privkey.pem
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
attributes  = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options. 
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix  : PrintableString, BMPString.
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings.
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: current versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings
# so use this option with caution!
string_mask = nombstr

req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName   = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default  = AU
countryName_min   = 2
countryName_max   = 2

stateOrProvinceName  = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State

localityName   = Locality Name (eg, city)

0.organizationName  = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName  = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName  = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName   = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_max   = 64

emailAddress   = Email Address
emailAddress_max  = 40

# SET-ex3   = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword  = A challenge password
challengePassword_min  = 4
challengePassword_max  = 20

unstructuredName  = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType   = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment   = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl  = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

# This is what PKIX recommends but some broken software chokes on critical
# extensions.
#basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
# So we do this instead.
basicConstraints = CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you that it should be possible, but I had the same trouble and found at http://blog.simonandkate.net/20140411/self-signed-openssl-subjectaltname that there is a wonderful long-lasting bug mentioned at https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#bugs :

> Extensions in certificates are not transferred to certificate requests
>   and vice versa.

My workaround was to create a config file 'test.cnf' that contains a specification of all the extensions I wanted, e.g.

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name  = req_dn
req_extensions      = req_exts 

[req_dn]
commonName          = my_name
#emailAddress       = 
#countryName            = 
#organizationName       = 
#organizationalUnitName     = 
#localityName           = 
#stateOrProvinceName        = 

[req_exts]
basicConstraints = CA:false
keyUsage = dataEncipherment, keyEncipherment, digitalSignature, nonRepudiation 
extendedKeyUsage = emailProtection
subjectAltName=critical, email:my_address1, email:my_address2
```

and then to apply it with OpenSSL as follows:

```
openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -config test.cnf -out test.csr
```